# Why the character name "Johnny Utah"?

Tags: analysis, character, whiplash

Lately watching this incredibly inspiring film [Whiplash (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2582802/), I've heard this name "Johnny Utah" in the movie.

When Andrew Neiman was late for the competition, he tries to convince Fletcher for being late and Ryan interrupts in the middle then Andrew says,

> Hey, f*** off, Johnny Utah.
>   Turn my pages, bi***.

Intrigued by the name, did some googling and found out from the [IMDB connections](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2582802/movieconnections) that the name was referred to a character from the movie "Point Break (1991)".

I have not seen "Point Break" but I would like to know why Andrew was referring Ryan as *Johnny Utah*.

Comment: And I haven't seen *Whiplash* and when reading the title of this question I thought you were asking why *Johnny Utah* from *Point Break* was named that way. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Is it better to add "Whiplash" in the title to avoid confusion?

Comment: Oh, I don't think so. It already has the tag and whoever reads the question knows what's going on anyway. That comment was really just a (supposedly) humorous anecdote than a serious problem with the question.

Comment: "Inspiring" film?  It's an excellent film but I wouldn't say it is particularly inspiring me to anything other than how NOT to teach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Johnny Utah (Keanu Reeves) from the movie Point Break was a cocky, over-confident, off-the-cuff kind of guy.  I believe his character played college Football but was injured in a championship game, so he opted for a career in law enforcement.

I would say he was referenced because of his attitude of being self-important.  It was more of a put-down than a compliment.

Comment: I understood it was not a compliment by the way Andrew was yelling at him and now I understand why he yelled Utah, because he's cocky and over-confident. Thanks.

Comment: Given the scene in question, insulting someone for being overconfident and self-important seems just a *teensy* bit hypocritical.

Answer (score -1):

In the movie, Point Break, Johnny Utah is a former Ohio State Buckeyes quarterback and rookie FBI Agent. He is assigned to "assist" experienced agent and veteran, Angelo Pappas, in investigating a string of bank robberies by the Ex-Presidents.So by that Andrew meant that he wanted to get "assisted" by Ryan!